# Зачем в React Native проекте сразу два инструмента сборки (buck и metro)?

Tags: react-native, metro

Есть ли какая-нибудь рациональная причина, по которой в одном проекте, сгенерированным `npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript`, присутствуют сразу Buck (на что указывает файл `.buckconfig`) и Metro (на что указывает файл `.metro.config.js`)?